# name attribute of <input> Element of HTML forms be omitted

Tags: html

I know that if an input element of html form does not have name attribute it will not be sent at all but i saw a webpage that gets user informations like  password and the input element of its html form does not have name attribute

so do you have any idea that how does such pages sends user password to the server?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways in which the data could be sent from an HTML client.

If you could provide a link to the website in which you saw it, I could may be look and tell.

They probably used **"XMLHttpRequest"** asynchronous mode to get and send data to the server.

Take a look at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest